# dynamic programming in functional languages

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I study haskell. I encounter with the problem that I cannot save intermediate calculation steps. It feels ineffective. How to use dynamic programming in functional programming?

Comment: You could use continuations and closures for storing intermediate values: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language#Functional_programming

Comment: This question is too abstract. Can you give a specific problem you want to solve, please? Bonus points if it's so concrete that there's actually some code that doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I haven't done much dynamic programming in Haskell so far, but it feels like laziness and purity will be your friends here. Just construct a data type representing you intermediate values (your Viterbi lattice, for instance) and use a recursive algorithm to populate it with values.

If you make your question more concrete I can try to help more.

Comment: There are a number of Viterbi algorithm implementations, by the by, [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmm/0.1/doc/html/src/Data-HMM.html), and [here](http://people.eecs.ku.edu/~esp/publications/c2009ItcTristan.pdf) might be worth perusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I encounter [in Haskell] the problem that I cannot save intermediate
>   calculation steps.

I do not know what ressources you used to learn it, but they were apparently not the best.

For example:

```
let 
    intermediate = {- calculation step -}
in ...
```

saves the result of a calculation step in `intermediate`. (Better: it binds the variable `intermediate` to the value. )

In addition, to cite the relevant Wikipedia  entry:

> In mathematics, computer science, and economics, dynamic programming
>   is a method for solving complex problems by breaking them down into
>   simpler subproblems. It is applicable to problems exhibiting the
>   properties of overlapping subproblems[1] and optimal substructure
>   (described below). When applicable, the method takes far less time
>   than naive methods.
>
> The key idea behind dynamic programming is quite simple. In general,
>   to solve a given problem, we need to solve different parts of the
>   problem (subproblems), then combine the solutions of the subproblems
>   to reach an overall solution. Often, many of these subproblems are
>   really the same. The dynamic programming approach seeks to solve each
>   subproblem only once, thus reducing the number of computations: once
>   the solution to a given subproblem has been computed, it is stored or
>   "memo-ized": the next time the same solution is needed, it is simply
>   looked up. This approach is especially useful when the number of
>   repeating subproblems grows exponentially as a function of the size of
>   the input.

It is obvious that this style of problem solving is supported by Haskell quite nicely. For example, in the easiest case one could carry a map around, that keeps the already solved sub-problems and their solutions. More advanced approach could use the State Monad. And so on.